# i can't find the element by xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to find out the xpath element on below. what would be the xpath?

***precise location (GPS and network-based)***

here is HTML code.

```
<div class="permission-bucket" jsinstance="1" jstcache="75">
<div class="bucket-icon-and-title" jstcache="87">
<jsl jstcache="110">
</div>
<div style="display:none" jstcache="88"/>
 <ul class="bucket-description" jstcache="89">
 <li jsinstance="0" jstcache="90">read your contacts</li>
 <li jsinstance="*1" jstcache="90">modify your contacts</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="permission-bucket" jsinstance="2" jstcache="75">
 <div class="bucket-icon-and-title" jstcache="87">
 <div style="display:none" jstcache="88"/>
 <ul class="bucket-description" jstcache="89">
 ***<li jsinstance="0" jstcache="90">precise location (GPS and network-based)</li>***
 <li jsinstance="*1" jstcache="90">approximate location (network-based)</li>
```

Comment: There are many XPaths possible for selecting any node.  State your requirements and exactly what you're trying to select.  The element containing "precise location (GPS and network-based)"?  The text after "precise location"?   Also, you've asked 7 questions, never [**accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) any answers, and seem to be having trouble writing clear questions.  Please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes thank you for the reply. i want the text "precise location (GPS and network-based)" and i dont know how to find the xpath for it.

Comment: /ul[@class="bucket-description"]/li[@jsinstance="0"]

Comment: Your HTML is not well-formed, so it cannot be queried via XPath.  Your HTML is not formatted, so you're asking readers to strain to read it.  You've not added clear requirements after being prompted for clarification.   You could be getting great help if you'd put the time into writing a clear question.   Good luck.

Comment: @kjh here is the site: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca. Then click View details in Permission and there is Location info which i want to find out the xpath element... hope this clear my question...

Comment: @splash58 thank you for the reply. i tried that and it doesn't print the value. here is my xpath i used: (By.xpath("//ul[@class='bucket-description']/li[@jsinstance='0']"))

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

```
//body/div/div/div/div/ul/li[text()="precise location (GPS and network-based)"]
```

or

```
//li[text()="precise location (GPS and network-based)"]
```

Comment: We don't know if such an XPath expression makes sense because we only see a tiny fraction of the document. Think about it: there might be other `li` elements that also contain "precise location (GPS" and so on. Instead of guessing an answer you should insist that the OP give more information (here, not in an off-site link).

Comment: @MathiasMüller here is the site: play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca. Then click View details under Permission and you will pop up window. i dont know whether is modal dialog or just subwindow. There is Location info which i want to find out the xpath element... hope you can help me...

Comment: I don't think that that's our concern. His question is pretty straight forward and i've given him a straight forward answer, it wasn't hard for me and i would like to think that i helped the guy.

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123 try the code in this answer.

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123 There is a policy on Stackoverflow that requires askers to give _all_ necessary information for a question _here_, not somewhere else. But don't just dump all the HTML here: please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PirreLeSang i tried both but it just stuck and doesnt do anything....so this element  is in pop up window

Comment: @PirreLeSang: Your intentions are noble, but you're chasing an elusive and unworthy goal.  The question is too poorly stated to answer, and attempting to answer before OP fixes his post only serves to encourage him to continue his history of posting unclear and incomplete questions.

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123 then probably you should give more info like everybody says, cause with hmtl you provided those xpath selectors work just fine.